# Why does trying to run a python executable return ': No such file or directory' after transferring it to server via FTP?

Tags: scripting, windows, ftp, executable, shebang

I'm having an issue where when I transfer a Python file to my VPS via FTP and try to run it using `./foo.py` I am returned with the error: `: No such file or directory`.

The error seems to indicate that the file I am trying to execute does not exist. But I can run the program with no problems using `python foo.py` which leads me to believe that the error actually probably means something else.

At first I thought it could be an issue with the shebang line, so I copied all of the content of the file and pasted it into a new file on the VPS that had not been transferred via FTP. The two files had exactly the same content but when I ran the new file using `./bar.py` it ran as expected.

So I've come to the conclusion that this could be an issue with the way that it is transferred. I have switched between ASCII and binary but both of these transfer methods give the same error.

Is it possible to stop this from happening?

Comment: On your VPS, does `cat -vet ./foo.py | head -1` show any `^M` characters?

Comment: Yes: `root@vps:/home# cat -vet ./foo.py | head -1` returns `#!/usr/bin/env python^M$`

Comment: Can you tell us the two OS's you're using, on the originating system and the VPS?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Both the VPS and my PC are both on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you edit the file at some point on a Windows PC, perchance?

Comment: @roaima I've definitely never edited it on a windows PC. I've edited it on a mac but that's UNIX so it shouldn't have made a different should it? :)

Comment: But I think that this happens sometime in the transfer over FTP because on my local system there is no `^M` but after transferring it onto the remote system the `^M` appears. I am using filezilla as the FTP client.

Comment: Mac is not Unix. Mac uses `\r` for line endings. Unix uses `\n`. Windows uses both. Pleased to see you're sorted.

Comment: @roaima Hmm, most sites say that OS X is unix - but it doesn't matter :) I found that transferring in ASCII added the `^M` but if I transferred in Binary the `^M` wasn't added. Thanks everyone for the help - I've got this sorted now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when a file contains `\r\n` as a line terminator instead of `\n`, since `\r` is a [C0 control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) meaning "go to the beginning of the current line".

To fix, run `dos2unix foo.py`.

Example session:

```
ben@joyplim /tmp/cr % echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' > foo.py
ben@joyplim /tmp/cr % chmod +x foo.py 
ben@joyplim /tmp/cr % ./foo.py 
ben@joyplim /tmp/cr % unix2dos foo.py 
unix2dos: converting file foo.py to DOS format ...
ben@joyplim /tmp/cr % ./foo.py       
: No such file or directory
ben@joyplim /tmp/cr % ./foo.py 2>&1 | xxd 
0000000: 2f75 7372 2f62 696e 2f65 6e76 3a20 7079  /usr/bin/env: py
0000010: 7468 6f6e 0d3a 204e 6f20 7375 6368 2066  thon.: No such f
0000020: 696c 6520 6f72 2064 6972 6563 746f 7279  ile or directory
0000030: 0a                                       .
```

Specifically note the `0d3a` in the output.

Comment: Thanks man! This worked. Really appreciate the help from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a file permission issue?

$ chmod +x foo.py

If you don't specifically indicate you wish to maintain then they are stripped/altered by most ftp clients.

Comment: I don't think so as the file has been made executable :)